# How many conditions can you have in a conditional split in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have been learning SSIS in my job and I wanted to know whether there are limits to how many conditions we are allowed to have in a conditional split transformation.

Comment: Did you have a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/conditional-split-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: I just reread the documentation and it states one or more, but does not give a limit.

Answer (score 2):

100 works. If you have that many conditions, you might be doing something ... unusual.

Here's a shot of a simple data flow. An OLE DB Source query which just generates an increasing sequence of numbers. It hits a conditional split which has an output for each value and it flows to a derived column (so we can see that it worked).

[image]

Even with a 1390 pixel wide screen, you can't see the entirety of the data flow. Layout doesn't matter for execution purposes but it's painful to open.

[image]

I can create a package with 1000 conditional split options but a data flow with that many conditions is going to be *very* slow to open.

[Biml](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress) makes for a great way to create packages to test these situations. Change the value of max to test your scenarios and ensure the Connection points to a valid database instance.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#
int max = 10;
#>
    <Connections>
        <Connection Name="tempdb" ConnectionString="Data Source=.\DEV2017;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" />
    </Connections>    
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO_67077940">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT CSPL Max">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="OLESRC Get data" ConnectionName="tempdb">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT TOP (<#=max#>) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn FROM sys.all_columns AS AC;</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <ConditionalSplit Name="CSPL Max">
                            <OutputPaths>
<#
for(int current = 0; current <= max; current++)
{
#>                                
                                <OutputPath Name="Out<#=current#>" ><Expression>[rn] == <#=current#></Expression></OutputPath>
<#
}
#>
                            </OutputPaths>
                        </ConditionalSplit>
<#
for(int current = 0; current <= max; current++)
{
#>
    <DerivedColumns Name="DER<#=current#>">
        <InputPath OutputPathName="CSPL Max.Out<#=current#>" />
    </DerivedColumns>
<#
}
#>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
<#

#>
</Biml>
```